# Segmentation Fault when accessing command line argument ~ CS50

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

i'm new to CS and have been tackling cs50. its been a great experience so far as I was a math major and most of the concepts and assignments have been clicking really well.

i know part of the learning process is to solve your bugs yourself, but after a few hours staring at the one line that i narrowed down is causing the segmentation fault, I'm getting pretty frustrated.

I've attached my code below. i spent an hour watching a tutorial on pointers but still can't narrow down why I can pass in argv[1] to my function validateKey() but can't access the memory when i try to use it.

I saw experienced programmers stating that its crucial to be able to identify where exactly the segmentation fault is arising, so after debugging I noticed anytime in the program I try to access argv[1] (whether in main or local), that memory access is restricted

greatly appreciate your time and support!

```
        #include <cs50.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <ctype.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <math.h>
        
        int findIndex(char keyVal);
        void cipherText(string s, string key);
        bool validateKey(string s);
        
        string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        
        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {
        
            if (argc != 2)
            {
                printf("Usage ./substitution key\n");
                return (1);
            }
        
            int length = strlen(argv[1]);
        
            if (length != 26)
            {
                printf("Key must contain 26 characters\n");
                return (1);
            }
            else
            {
                if (validateKey(argv[1])) //allows to pass argv[1]
                {
                    string userText = get_string("plaintext: ");
                    cipherText(userText, argv[1]); //allows to pass
                    printf("\n");
                    return (0);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Usage ./substitution key\n");
                    return (1);
                }
            }
        
        }
        
        bool validateKey(string s)
        {
        
            int n = strlen(s);
            int hash[n][1];
        
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int b;
        
                if (isdigit(s[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                b = s[i];
        
                if (hash[b][0] == 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else hash[b][0] = 1;
        
            }
            return true;
        }
        
        int findIndex(char keyVal)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                if (alphabet[i] == tolower(keyVal) || alphabet[i] == toupper(keyVal))
                {
                    return i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        
        void cipherText(string s, string key)
        {
            printf("ciphertext: ");
        
            for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
            {
                if (!(isalnum(s[i])) || isdigit(s[i]))
                {
                    printf("%c", s[i]);
                    continue;
                }
                int index = findIndex(s[i]);
                if (index < 0) break;
        
                if (isupper(s[i]))
                {
                    printf("%c", toupper(key[index])); //SEGMENTATIONF
                    continue;
                }
               else if (islower(s[i]))
               {
                    printf("%c", tolower(key[index]));
               }
               else printf("%c", s[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `validateKey` invokes UB. Run it in your debugger, put a breakpoint on `b = s[i];`, single-step that line, look at the value of `b`, then consider the size of `hash` and what you're about to dereference.

Comment: You are indexing `hash[b][0] = 1;` where `b` is data from the string. This is unrelated to the length of the string, used to define the array `int n = strlen(s); int hash[n][1];` so you are probably indexing out of bounds. Note too, you are testing an array that you did not initialise, so `if (hash[b][0] == 1)` is not useful.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Weather Vane: appreciate your guys immediate responses, super helpful for a beginner like me . as for validateKey, in my head that function would take each letter from the string (the key/string must have all unique characters), and b = s[i] would typecast that character to its ASCII value. and then i stored each occurence in hash[int(char)][XXX] so if i ever had a repeat character i could return false and exit the program completely

Comment: i guess i tried to use it as a hashMap but now im seeing that indexing is probably messed up

Comment: @WhozCraig     if (hash[b][] == 1) is to check if there was already an occurence of that letter, why is it not useful? thanks for the help again

Comment: That was my remark. The array has not been initialised, so when you first check that element, its value is indeterminate. Fill the array with `0` just after it is defined, and increase the size from `n` to `256`. Finally, watch out for indexing by a poisssibly negative value when `char` is signed (it usually is).

Comment: @wonton Too far ahead. What is `b`, and how big is the superior dimension of `hash` . *Do what I said*. Run this in a debugger and examine the value of `b` after the line I specified.

Comment: Quick note.  a way to initialize any multi-dimensional array is to use `{{0}}`, eg: `int hash[n][1] = {{0}};` thus setting all elements to zero.  `memset(hash, 0, sizeof hash);` also works.  The important thing is to do it, one way or the other.